# Changing display none to block in devTools

Tags: css, ng-hide

Is it possible to show some special (surprise) image to the user who is changing display property from "none" to "block" in Developer Tools?

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to understand what you want without showing any examples.

If I understand you:

```js
function show() {
    document.getElementById("show").style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
#show{
  display:none
}
```

```html
<div id="show">not hidden</div>
<button onclick="show()" >show</button>
```

Or I haven't understood you...

Answer (score 0):

As long as the image is loaded in the DOM, yes, it could be made visible by doing that. I'm not sure why you would want to do that, but you may.